# Best method for transferring data between Access database to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, ado.net, odbc

I have recently been assigned a task to build a c# windows forms app. It needs to read large amounts of data from an Access database and transfer to a SQL database, deleting old SQL data before transferring.

I have never done anything like this before and was wondering what the best approach would be ?

Also, do I need to read each Access table individually and save them in different datasets e.g dataset1, dataset2 for each table ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sql Server Integration Services..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to implement your own transfer mechanism in your C# application and you really are working with large amounts of data then be careful to choose a method that does not end up inserting the data into SQL Server row-by-row. Clearly an approach like

```cs
OdbcDataReader rdrAccess = cmdAccess.ExecuteReader();
while (rdrAccess.Read())
{
    // insert a row into SQL Server
}
```

will almost certainly be slow, but even a single Access SQL statement like

```cs
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connAccess;
    cmd.CommandText = 
        $"INSERT INTO [ODBC;{connStrSqlOdbc}].[BulkTable] (id, txtcol) " +
        $"SELECT ID, TextField AS txtcol FROM Table1 WHERE ID<=1000";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

will end up sending 1000 individual T-SQL statements of the form

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO  "dbo"."BulkTable"  ("id","txtcol") VALUES (@P1,@P2)',N'@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(50)',1,N'record000000'
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO  "dbo"."BulkTable"  ("id","txtcol") VALUES (@P1,@P2)',N'@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(50)',2,N'record000001'
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO  "dbo"."BulkTable"  ("id","txtcol") VALUES (@P1,@P2)',N'@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(50)',3,N'record000002'
...
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO  "dbo"."BulkTable"  ("id","txtcol") VALUES (@P1,@P2)',N'@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(50)',1000,N'record000999'
```

to the SQL Server.

Probably your best bet would be to use `System.Data.SqlClient` and a [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) object, like so

```cs
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connAccess;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, TextField AS txtcol FROM Table1 WHERE ID<=1000";
    using (OdbcDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        using (var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connStrSqlClient))
        {
            sbc.DestinationTableName = "BulkTable";
            sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);
        }
    }
}
```

On my test network, the `SqlBulkCopy` approach consistently finished in less than one-tenth of the time that the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` method took.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tool called SQL Server Integration Services ([SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx))
This is tool for your task and this is something you want to use.

Alternatively you could craft something in .net, but using datasets is horrible idea, because of memory, performance and since you mention huge data...

Or you could use [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) construct to read MSAccess file and transfer data to SQL using SQL query.

and probably dozen of other ways to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You  can simply create method containing following code,

```
 OleDbConnection accessConnection = new OleDbConnection("connectionStringForAccess");
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connectionStringForSql");
                    accessConnection.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT*FROM YourAccessTableName", accessConnection);
                    OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    sqlCommand command = new sqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE YourTableName;",sqlConnection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection);
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "YourTableName";
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                    accessConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?